# Is there a way to force full key caching for a given table in Cassandra?

Tags: cassandra

This would be lovely, since some cf have a limited number of keys, or queries are intensive on these keys, etc.

Thx

Edit : to be more precise, I'm interested in the partition key disk-location caching for a given table.

Edit 2 : This thread seems to give the answer http://cassandra-user-incubator-apache-org.3065146.n2.nabble.com/What-is-substituting-keys-cached-column-family-argument-td7584136.html 
Cassandra now prevents any manual tuning for keys or row caching (that used to be allowed with the keys_cached or rows_cahed arguments on a per-CF basis), and instead uses its own global caching manager. This is annoying in the specific case of CFs that are not often queried, but from which we expect low latency. Obviously this is my case. Anyone from Apache/Datastax could tell me if there is any chance this might evolve? Thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a range of keys that are being queried frequently across a Cassandra cluster, Cassandra's built-in keycache will retain those values in memory for you automatically on a per-column family basis.

[The keycache is turned on by default](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/maximizing-cache-benefit-with-cassandra), so no configuration changes are necessary.

Now if your question pertains to being able to have Cassandra automatically warm the keycache for the entire key range for any column families you specify, I don't believe this is possible, [at least according to the Cassandra 2.0 documentation](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/2.0/webhelp/index.html#cassandra/operations/ops_configuring_caches_c.html#concept_ds_n35_nnr_ck).

Your best option, if you *really, really* need to warm the cache yourself instead of letting it happen at runtime, would be to create your own startup application that queries your desired key ranges at startup.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, very clear. Cache warming by myself would be nice, but my problem is that the queries I need do not depend only on the partition key, but also on the clustering key... It would be a good idea for cassandra devs to implement this feature, it does not seem very costly!

Comment: @Nicko Got it. Your best bet for that type of caching is the rowcache. This will keep an entire "row" in memory. You have to remember that CQL3 really does an under-the-hood translation of Cassandra rows and columns. Your partition key is really a low-level Thrift row key, and your clustering key is really a Thrift column name.

I'm not much of an expert on the rowcache because our loads are so write-heavy, but here's a URL which explains it: http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/maximizing-cache-benefit-with-cassandra

Comment: I considered doing that, but my rows are way too big! I thought Cassandra could handle the following procedure (maybe it will someday) : retrieve the wide row location via the cached partition key, and then complete the query given the other EQs... I even believe that this is what they actually do, except for the "full" key caching... Maybe I could "simulate" a intensive use of these tables to force them in cache, but that's wild ;)